# Extract some dates using regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I want to extract some dates from some sentences using regex. Kindly help.

- "Ujjwal was born on 12th day of August 1998". Here extract "12th day of August 2010"
- "Rahul started the business on 30th day of June, 2003". Here extract "30th day of June,
  2003"
- "RK was married on 18 th .day of March 2008". Extract "18 th .day of March 2008"
- "Raj had a baby on 11 day of June, 2012". Extract "11 day of June, 2012"

I want to extract these dates using regex in Python.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a python person, so this is written in JavaScript, but regular expressions are fairly independent of language.

```js
var sentences = ["Ujjwal was born on 12th day of August 1998",
  "Rahul started the business on 30th day of June, 2003",
  "RK was married on 18 th .day of March 2008",
  "Raj had a baby on 11 day of June, 2012"];

sentences.forEach((sentence) => {
  var result = sentence.match(/on (.*)/);
  if (result) {
    console.log("result: ",result[1]);
  }
});
```

Not elegant at all, but it answers your question by taking everything after "on ". Also, your example "18 th .day" seems a bit odd. Would anyone really put a period in there?

If you want a bit more break down, there are many ways to use regular expressions, the expression below is a bit more robust. However, you are parsing language and that can complicate things. This expression works for the 4 sentences you supplied, but it might not work for the 5th.

```js
var sentences = ["Ujjwal was born on 12th day of August 1998",
  "Rahul started the business on 30th day of June, 2003",
  "RK was married on 18 th .day of March 2008",
  "Raj had a baby on 11 day of June, 2012"];
  
sentences.forEach((sentence) => {
  var result = sentence.match(/(\w+)\s+(.*)\s+on\s+(\d+).*day.+((?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Nov|Dec)\w*)\D*(\d+)\b/);
  if (result) {
    // console.log(result);
    var name = result[1];
    var what = result[2];
    var day = result[3];
    var month = result[4];
    var year = result[5];
    var date = month + " " + day + ", " + year;
    console.log("Name: ", name);
    console.log("What: ", what);
    console.log("When: ", date);
  }
});
```